# Filter a one to many relation record result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to filter the results given from a one to many relation directly from the model object, but I cant find the right way.
Here, the relations:

I have a User model that can subscript to many companies (company model), and a company can have many users subscripted to it, so, is a many to many relation.

In every company, this user has a personal info, so, every user, could have many profiles (profile model) one for each company that is subscripted to.
So It is a one to many relation.

Imagine I want to retrieve the company that a user is currently viewing directly from the model, this, Im achieving by filtering the many to many relation:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
///
 public function obtainLoggedOnCompany()
 {
   return $this->belongsToMany('app\Company', 'user_company', 'id', 'company_id')->withPivot('selected')->wherePivot('selected', 1)  
 }
```

Then, if I want to return the selected company in a blade view I just call:

Auth::user()->obtainLoggedOnCompany->first();

All thanks to the withPivot and wherePivot clause.

Different is the case when I want to retrieve the registered profile of a currently selected company, I tried:

```
public function obtainSelectedProfile()
{
$SelectedCompany= $this->obtainLoggedOnCompany->first();

return $this->hasMany('app\Profile','user_id')->where('company_id', '=', $SelectedCompany->company_id);
}
```

But it throws a Trying to get property of non object Exception.
Is there another way to filter one to many relations directly in the model relation function?

Iam using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you do:

I assume that your Company.php model has

```
public function userProfile(){
return $this->hasMany('app\Profile','company_id');
}
```

And Try this on the controller:

```
    $company_id=1; //suppose the current company viewing id is 1
        $user = User::where('id',Auth::id())->with(['obtainLoggedOnCompany'=>function($query) use($company_id){
        $query->where('company_id',$company_id);
        $query->with(['company_user_profile'=>function($query){
         $query->where('user_id',Auth::id());
         $query->last();
        }]);
        //$query->last();
        }])->first();
```

And you can fetch the profile using:

```
dd($user->obtainLoggedOnCompany->company_user_profile);
```

Comment: I actually wanted to call a method directly in the model object, but I think I will have to get the current user in the controller before calling the home view. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by passing variable to eager loading and updating your relationship structure. Try this

`User` Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ///
    public function obtainLoggedOnCompany()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'user_company', 'user_id', 'company_id'); 
    }

}
```

`Company` Model:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    ///
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'company_id');  
    }
}
```

`Example` A use case of this:

```
$user_id = 1;
$user = User::where('id', $user_id)->with(['company' => function($query) use ($user_id) {

           return $query->with(['profile' => function($query2) use ($user_id) {
                                              return $query2->where('user_id', $user_id);
                                            }]);
        }])->first();
// $user variable contains user details, company details, and profile
```

Comment: That data would be returned by a controller, right?

Comment: Yes, by a controller

Answer (score 0):

actually, this sentence works perfectly!:

```
public function obtainSelectedProfile()
{
$SelectedCompany= $this->obtainLoggedOnCompany->first();

return $this->hasMany('app\Profile','user_id')->where('company_id', '=', 
$SelectedCompany->company_id);
}
```

My error was elswhere on my view!

Though I think Its a better practice to prepare the data on the controller before passing it to the view, because I would have to query to server **every single time I want to get data from the user profile on the fly in the view.**